# Read the first name of an individual from firebase into a UILabel in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uilabel

I am successfully reading in the first name of an individual and can print this value in the console but how can I successfully pass this into a UILabel?

When I attempt to pass it as shown below I get the error "Value of type '(viewController) -> () -> viewController' has no member 'FirstName'"

var ref: DatabaseReference!

```
var FirstName: String?

func observeName() { // this is the function that will return the name of the individual to ensure that it is displayed on the HomeViewController
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child("profile").child(uid)
    ref.queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let firstName = value?["First Name"] as? String
        self.FirstName = firstName
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}


let welcomeText: UILabel = {
    let l = UILabel()
    l.text = "Hi...\(self.FirstName)"// WHERE I WANT THE NAME!!
    l.font = UIFont(name: "Optima-ExtraBlack", size: 30)
    l.textColor = .white
    return l
}()
```

I would expect this to return the name of the user that had just logged in. Any help would be amazing! been spinning my wheels on this.

Comment: Just set `welcomeText.text = firstName` in the completion handler of the firebase function. Also where are you storing the `var FirstName: String?` variable?

Comment: Boo-ya. Cheers mate! Thanks so much.

Comment: no problem glad it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `welcomeText.text = firstName` in the completion handler of the firebase function.